# No data in listview on device rotation

Tags: android, loader, android-cursorloader

Once the data is loaded and all set now if i rotate the device the list view is gone and there is no more data i have to restart the app to load data,but when device is offline and i load data just from table it retains the data even on rotation

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Boolean>{

Toolbar tb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initilize();
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    tb.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if(isConnected){
        loadData();
    }else {
        Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), getResources().getString(R.string.noint), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        bar.show();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_list,new lvfrag()).commit();
}

private void initilize() {
    tb = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.menu_refresh :
            break;
        case R.id.menu_setting :
            Intent is = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Prefs.class);
            startActivity(is);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_about:
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            adb.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            adb.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.abt));
            adb.create();
            adb.show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public Loader<Boolean> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new Loade(this);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Boolean> loader, Boolean data) {
    setd(data);
}

private void setd(Boolean data) {
}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Boolean> loader) {
}

private void loadData() {
    if(getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0) == null) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
    } else {
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
    }
}

public static class lvfrag extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    CustomA ca;
    ListView lv;
    private static final int mId = 1001;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v("Added","");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_vw,container,false);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.frag_list);
        if(isConnected){
            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(weathertable.mContentUri,null,null);
            ca = new CustomA(getActivity(),null);
            lv.setAdapter(ca);
            loadfData();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent dt = new Intent(getActivity(),Detail.class);
                    dt.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(weathertable.mContentUri,String.valueOf(id)));
                    getActivity().startActivity(dt);
                }
            });
        }else {
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(weathertable.mContentUri,null,null,null,null);
            ca = new CustomA(getActivity(),c);
            lv.setAdapter(ca);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getResources().getString(R.string.cnt),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        switch (id){
            case mId:
                return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),weathertable.mContentUri,null,null,null,null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        ca.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        ca.swapCursor(null);
    }

    private void loadfData() {
        if(getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(mId) == null) {
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(mId, null, this).forceLoad();
        } else {
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(mId, null, this).forceLoad();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: hope this helps... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in android call `onConfigurationChanged` that you need to override to fix this.

Essentially, when you rotate the device the OS is forced to completely re instantiate the activity, losing its current state along with it.

If you create a field variable for your adapter, then set the variable further down in the class, you can call `setAdapter` in `onConfigurationChanged` to put the data back in the listview

Answer (score 0):

adding  : android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to the manifest solved the issue